Cannot make null a property with BeanUtilsBean copyProperties
I want to make a PATCH process :
@Path("/calendrier-serveur")
@PATCH
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response updateCalendrierServeur(TPosCalendrierServeur data) {
    try {
        TPosCalendrierServeur newData = service.updateCalendrierServeur(data);
        return Response.ok(newData, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Error occured while updating server calendar." + e.getStackTrace());
        Payload payload = new Payload("Invalid payload.",e.getMessage());
        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(payload).build();
    }
}

code of the service :
...
import org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtilsBean;
...
@Transactional
public TPosCalendrierServeur updateCalendrierServeur(TPosCalendrierServeur data) throws IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException {
    TPosCalendrierServeur original = calendrierServeurRepository.find("mmcUserId = ?1", data.getMmcUserId()).firstResult();
    BeanUtilsBean beanUtil = new NullAwareBeanUtilsBean();
    beanUtil.copyProperties(original, data);
            calendrierServeurRepository.getEntityManager().merge(original);
    original = calendrierServeurRepository.find("mmcUserId = ?1", data.getMmcUserId()).firstResult();
    return original;
}

I debugged the data when calling the service and I get data.getAbsenceDebut() = null before the copyProperties , but after the copyProperties then it remains the data of the original object from database.
So why is the property not set to null ?

Depending on which version of Hibernate ORM / Quarkus you're using, you may simply be affected by https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/38722, which is going to be fixed in Quarkus 3.11.
